# Dell Latitude E6510 touchpad has stopped working

Tags: touchpad

My fiancee got a Dell Latitude E6510 and all of a sudden the touchpad stopped working. I tried a lot of things, but the touchpad just won't work. I tried updating the drivers, downloading and installing the driver "DELL_MULTI-TOUCH_TOUCHPAD_A04_R269801" from Dell consumer support, and even updating the bios. I am really frustrated and don't know what else to do. Can someone please give me a hint on what I could do to get the touchpad to work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: try asking on superuser.com

Comment: Check if it's a hardware issue first. Boot it off of ubuntu live and see if it works then. If not -- return the laptop :-P

Comment: Sometimes modern laptops have an explicit switch to disable the touchpad ...

Comment: @Fiancee; so you know that this is a website for programming questions, why did you ask it here?

Comment: Is the touchpad enabled?  It's very easy to disable/enable it in Control Panel.